# document.RemoveChild not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

in book '*Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS*' (for Microsoft certification) is example of removing child from document (defined in onLoad function). But it doesn't work and throws following exception: 
**Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.**

I know that if I try to remove child from "outerDiv" node, it will work, but I have no idea why it is written like this in book. It's an mistake in book or I'm doing something wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <script>  
        window.onload = function () {
          var element = document.getElementById("innerDiv");      
          document.removeChild(element);     
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="outerDiv">
        <p class='mainPara'>Main Paragraph</p>
        <ul>
          <li>First List Item</li>
          <li>Second List Item</li>
          <li>Third List Item</li>
          <li>Fourth List Item</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="innerDiv">
          <p class='subPara' id='P1'>Paragraph 1</p>
          <p class='subPara' id='P2'>Paragraph 2</p>
          <p class='subPara' id='P3'>Paragraph 3</p>
          <p class='subPara' id='P4'>Paragraph 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: `innerChild` isn't the child of `document`, it's the child of `outerDiv`. Looks like a mistake in the book, have you checked the errata for it?

Comment: Unless you have a different version of the book (which is possible), the example shown [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=X1hEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT55&lpg=PT55&dq=programming+in+html5+with+javascript+and+css3+removechild+example&source=bl&ots=ssl2ccDxEe&sig=rzO0jGn3QIuxkZLDVJ4dYh5ep8I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRhtvs4KTKAhVC72MKHZesCtQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) is correct

Comment: @HowardRenollet I have exactly same version onf book, but when you look into [Altering the DOM](https://books.google.sk/books?id=X1hEBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT55&ots=ssl2ccDxEe&dq=programming%20in%20html5%20with%20javascript%20and%20css3%20removechild%20example&hl=sk&pg=PT50#v=onepage&q&f=false) section of the book, you will see example described in question.

Comment: @Lenka - I see.  Looks like just an error in the book... it happens more often than you would think.  The second example for `removeChild()` that I shared previously is correct, but you are right, the first one in that section is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

instead of:

```
document.removeChild(element);
```

Like @j08691 says, maybe is a book mistake :).

Comment: As @j08691 and HowardRenollet mentioned, it looks like misatke in book. Marking this as answer, because I cannot mark comment and your solution will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you, element is not direct child of document, so this (your code) will not work.

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```